# How to insert a Path in between an existing Path

Tags: graphhopper

I am working on an implementation to generate alternate Paths using via node method.

While checking for local optimality I do the following

```
forwardEdge = bestWeightMapFrom.get(viaNode);
reverseEdge = bestWeightMapTo.get(viaNode);

double unpackedUntilDistance = 0;
while(forwardEdge.edge != -1) {
   double parentDist = forwardEdge.parent != null ? forwardEdge.parent.distance : 0;
   double dist = forwardEdge.distance - parentDist;
   if(unpackedUntilDistance + dist >= T_THRESHOLD) {
     EdgeSkipIterState edgeState = (EdgeSkipIterState) graph.getEdgeProps(forwardEdge.edge, forwardEdge.adjNode);
     unpackStack.add(new EdgePair(edgeState, false));
     sV = forwardEdge.adjNode;
     forwardEdge = forwardEdge.parent;
     break;
   }
   else {
     unpackedUntilDistance += dist;
     forwardEdge = forwardEdge.parent;
     sV = forwardEdge.adjNode;
   }
 }
 int oldSV = forwardEdge.adjNode;
 EdgeEntry oldForwardEdge = forwardEdge;
```

I unpack the edge in the stack to further narrow down sV.
I get vT and oldVt in a similar fashion by traversing reverseEdge.

if I determine that the path from sV and vT is <= length of unpacked edges I accept this via node and construct the alternatePath as follows.

```
PathBidirRef p = (PathBidirRef) algo.calcPath(oldSV, oldVT);

Path4CHAlt p1 = new Path4CHAlt(graph, flagEncoder);
p1.setSwitchToFrom(false);
p1.setEdgeEntry(oldForwardEdge);
p1.segmentEdgeEntry = p.edgeEntry;
double weight = oldForwardEdge.weight + oldReverseEdge.weight + p.edgeEntry.weight + p.edgeTo.weight;
p1.setWeight(weight);
p1.edgeTo = oldReverseEdge;
p1.segmentEdgeTo = p.edgeTo;
Path p2 = p1.extract();
```

Path4CHAlt is

```
public class Path4CHAlt extends Path4CH {
    private boolean switchWrapper = false;
    public EdgeEntry segmentEdgeTo;
    public EdgeEntry segmentEdgeEntry;

    public Path4CHAlt( Graph g, FlagEncoder encoder )
    {
        super(g, encoder);
    }

    public Path4CHAlt setSwitchToFrom( boolean b )
    {
        switchWrapper = b;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Path extract()
    {
        System.out.println("Path4CHAlt extract");
        if (edgeEntry == null || edgeTo == null || segmentEdgeEntry == null || segmentEdgeTo == null)
            return this;

        if (switchWrapper)
        {
            EdgeEntry ee = edgeEntry;
            edgeEntry = edgeTo;
            edgeTo = ee;

            ee = segmentEdgeEntry;
            segmentEdgeEntry = segmentEdgeTo;
            segmentEdgeTo = ee;
        }

        EdgeEntry currEdge = segmentEdgeEntry;
        while (EdgeIterator.Edge.isValid(currEdge.edge))
        {
            processEdge(currEdge.edge, currEdge.adjNode);
            currEdge = currEdge.parent;
        }
        currEdge.parent = edgeEntry;

        currEdge = edgeEntry;
        while (EdgeIterator.Edge.isValid(currEdge.edge))
        {
            processEdge(currEdge.edge, currEdge.adjNode);
            currEdge = currEdge.parent;
        }
        setFromNode(currEdge.adjNode);
        reverseOrder();

        currEdge = segmentEdgeTo;
        int tmpEdge = currEdge.edge;
        while (EdgeIterator.Edge.isValid(tmpEdge))
        {
            currEdge = currEdge.parent;
            processEdge(tmpEdge, currEdge.adjNode);
            tmpEdge = currEdge.edge;
        }

        currEdge.parent = edgeTo;

        currEdge = edgeTo;
        tmpEdge = currEdge.edge;
        while (EdgeIterator.Edge.isValid(tmpEdge))
        {
            currEdge = currEdge.parent;
            processEdge(tmpEdge, currEdge.adjNode);
            tmpEdge = currEdge.edge;
        }
        setEndNode(currEdge.adjNode);
        return setFound(true);
    }
}
```

This is not working all the time. I get exceptions in Path4CH

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.graphhopper.routing.ch.Path4CH.expandEdge(Path4CH.java:62)
at com.graphhopper.routing.ch.Path4CH.processEdge(Path4CH.java:56)
at com.graphhopper.routing.PathBidirRef.extract(PathBidirRef.java:95)
at com.graphhopper.routing.DijkstraBidirectionRef.extractPath(DijkstraBidirectionRef.java:99)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AbstractBidirAlgo.runAlgo(AbstractBidirAlgo.java:74)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AbstractBidirAlgo.calcPath(AbstractBidirAlgo.java:60)
```

In Path

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Edge 1506012 was empty when requested with node 1289685, array index:0, edges:318
at com.graphhopper.routing.Path.forEveryEdge(Path.java:253)
at com.graphhopper.routing.Path.calcInstructions(Path.java:349)
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I could really use some help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, do you have a github clone or similar? Hard to see what is going wrong with this. Also I cannot really follow the reasoning why you need to insert a path. You need a list of paths here IMO. Also why are you getting two exceptions - one in Path and one in Path4CH?

Comment: Hi, I dont have it checked in yet. I am getting those two exceptions for different queries.

Comment: Which approach are you taking: an own custom one or one from a paper?

Comment: I tried to port the implementation from OSRM into graphhopper. Now that OSRM is released under BSD 2 clause license this should not be a problem.

Comment: And what strategy is OSRM using? Or are you porting without understanding ;) ?

Comment: :) they are using Via point routing. I did read a bunch of papers and implemented penalty weighting and now via point routing.

Comment: In GH with CH enabled can I get a shortest path from any nodeID to any other nodeID ?

Comment: sure you can, but not sure if I understand properly. Maybe we discuss this via our mailing list?

Comment: Hey, I figured out the issue with my code. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe you answer it yourself and accept it?

Comment: do you intend to publish the code as open source?

Comment: yes, i do plan to publish this as open source. i am working on something else right now. once i clean up the code and add unit test cases i will send a pull request

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

Inside DijkstraBidirectionRef.calcPath I was trying to calculate shortest path from an arbitrary node to source node and vertex node.

The error used to occur because the original call to calcPath was operating on QueryGraph and inside I was creating a new Object of DijkstraBidirectionRef using LevelGraphStorage.

This was a problem because QueryGraph may create virtual nodes and edges for source and target nodes. Call to calcPath(node, virtualNode) operating on LevelGraphStorage would throw an exception.

The fix was to call algo.setGraph(queryGraph) after creating DijkstraBidirectionRef.